# php function returns "Warning: Array to string conversion in"

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, foreach

I have the following PHP function where I am trying to explode an array and apply foreach loop on it to get a collective set of data. However, I am getting the error quoted in the subject.

```
function getSwipableUsers() {
  $expInt = explode(',', $f['interests']);

  $userDisplayData = array();
  foreach($expInt as $ints){
    $userDisplayData[] = "<div class='tag alert-primary'>".$ints."</div>";
  }

  $html = '<div class="user-distance mt-2">'.$userDisplayData.'</div>';
  return $html;
}
```

I rechecked again and again but everything seems fine to me. What's wrong with my code here?

Comment: `$userDisplayData` is an array which you try to string concatenate in `$html = '<div class="user-distance mt-2">'.$userDisplayData.'</div>';`

Comment: Yes, I see that. What's the fix?

Comment: You could define `$userDisplayData` as a string and concatenate those divs to it or use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with an empty string separator to convert the array to a string.

Comment: @Remy got it.. Thanks :)

Comment: Instead of pushing `"<div class='tag alert-primary'>".$ints."</div>"` to `$userDisplayData[]`, concatenate these strings to `$html` directly or else re-iterate the `$userDisplayData` and append all strings to `$html`

Comment: @Haridarshan if you see my comment right above yours, I actually figured it out. But thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, the *$userDisplayData* variable is an array, and you are trying to assign a string space to it.

You could do it this way:

```php
function getSwipableUsers() {
    $expInt = explode(',', $f['interests']);
  
    $userDisplayData = '<div class="tagsection">';

    foreach($expInt as $ints){
      $userDisplayData .= "<div class='tag alert-primary'>".$ints."</div>";
    }

    $userDisplayData .= '</div>';

    $html = '<div class="user-distance mt-2">'.$userDisplayData.'</div>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I already figured it out after @Remy hinted about concatenating. But accepting your answer to let others know that this is the right approach which I used.